# WPF UserControl.Resources reference

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, radcombobox

I am try to start learning `WPF` and i am using `Telerik`.
So i start with simple `ComboBox` in [this](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radcombobox/populating-with-data/binding-to-object#using-displaymemberpath) article and this is my control:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox Height="20" Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataSource}, Path=Agency}"></telerik:RadComboBox>
```

What i am trying to do now is to bind an object but first to declare a resource in the XAML (from the article):

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <example:AgencyViewModel x:Key="DataSource"/> // AgencyViewModel is a class 
</UserControl.Resources>
```

So my problem is that after `UserControl` i don't have the option `Resources`, i try to put it inside my control, so i be happy to understand how this is working in `WPF`

Comment: Try to search on Telerik site for how to use [RadComboBox](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radcombobox/overview.html)

Comment: This is what i try, am i doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 8):

You have to set the **DataContext** dependency property on a parent control in relation to your ComboBox. The DataContext is then inherited by all (logical-)children. You can then **bind** to properties on the object referenced by  the DataContext dependency property. You do that by referencing the **x:Key** of your resource with a **StaticResource Markup Extension** construct.

```
<UserControl>
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <example:AgencyViewModel x:Key="DataSource"/> // AgencyViewModel is a class 
  </UserControl.Resources>

  <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource DataSource}">

    <telerik:RadComboBox Height="20" Width="200" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsCollectionDefinedInViewModel}" />

  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

You can also do it as it is done in the article without setting the DataContext but instead setting the **Source** of the binding explicilty.

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataSource}, Path=Agency}"
```

Comment: And this 2 ways are the same ?

Comment: Please see my control update, i try the second way and got compiler error: the resource "DataSource" could not resolved

Comment: No. A Binding must have a source!!! In the first case (my code) WPF sets the source of the binding to the object that is referenced by the datacontext. This happens when no source, relativesource or elementname are specified in a binding expression. In the second case the source is set explicitly. I recommend you read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: The resource key that you reference with the staticresource markup extension has to be defined in the resuorce section on a parent element and in the same namescope, i.e. same tree structure. For more help please post the entire xaml.